# Adding noise to the flat real projective plane

Tags: statistics, algebraic-topology

Of course we can think of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ as the unit interval with sides identified as follows:
[image: Real projective plane identification]

This is not too hard to implement into any programming you like and then of course you could randomly select sample points from this. What I would like to do is to add a little noise to these sample points so they don't necessarily lie on $\mathbb{RP}^2$ but rather near it. The problem I am having with this is how should I add the noise? Obviously I can add Gaussian noise in 2D but this does encapsulate points being slightly "away" from the manifold.

I may end up having to use a more conventional representation of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ or something and add noise this way but that feels much less satistfying.

Comment: What does it mean for a point to be "near" $\mathbb{RP}^2$? It's like asking, "I have some numbers on the real line; I want to add some noise so that they are no longer on the real line." It doesn't make sense unless you specify an embedding into a larger space, maybe $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb R^3$ or something else, and then the answer will depend on the embedding.

Comment: Choosing sample points that "don't necessarily lie on $\mathbf{RP}^{2}$ but [instead] near it" requires that you specify 1. an embedding of $\mathbf{RP}^{2}$ into 2. some probability space. I'm guessing you have some "ulterior motive", e.g., a need to choose "a random line" or "a random direction" in space...? If so, those details are essential to the question.

Comment: @Rahul ah very true. I guess if instead of considering just the unit square I added some noise in 3 dimensions and then made the identifications (identifying opposite planes rather than edges in this case) this would achieve a somewhat randomised $\mathbb{RP}^2$ right? I've phrased this all quite poorly - I apologise!

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang the ulterior motive is to compute the persistent homology groups of this perturbed projective plane and have it hopefully be the same as the homology groups for $\mathbb{RP}^2$.

Comment: I suppose that would be the simplest way to go about it, yes. Though don't take my word for it as I know very little about homology, whether persistent or otherwise.

Comment: @Rahul wonderful, I guess this boils down to if a cuboid with opposite faces identified with a twist is also homotopic to $\mathbb{RP}^2$ which I think obviously is as we can retract the cuboid to the unit square. Think some extra justification may be required however - I'll think about.

Comment: I'm no expert, but where I've seen persistent homology, it's used to give topological structure to a set of points in some Euclidean space (e.g., the set of atoms in a protein molecule), not to an abstract topological space. Is that the type of goal you're after? Have you tried this on an easier space, such as a sphere or a torus?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang yes I realise these are the applications, this is more a demonstration/thought exercise as to what could be done. I have done it on a simpler example yes, namely a figure eight.

Comment: Maybe you want it embedded in $\Bbb{RP^2\times R}$?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger perhaps so? Not entirely sure how I'd implement this at all to solve my original problem however.